# Why I cannot pass positional argument in Django rest-framework unittest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest

I have implemented a test method which is like below:

```
request = self.factory.get(reverse('users:user-details', kwargs={'user_id': 'd6cb0d1850241a04caaae516f27762d0c0cbc716'}))
response = UserDetailsAPIView.as_view()(request)
```

The URL path is as below:

```
url(
        r'users/(?P<user_id>\w+)/details/?$',
        UserDetailsAPIView.as_view(),
        name='user-details'
)
```

And it's API view is as below:

```
class UserDetailsAPIView(APIView):
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get(self, request, user_id, *args, **kwargs):
```

Why I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/vagrant/apps/users/tests/test_views.py", line 95, in test_get_user_detail_by_user_id
    response = UserDetailsAPIView.as_view()(request)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing as kwargs instead of args.

Replace this:

```
request = self.factory.get(reverse('users:user-details', args=('d6cb0d1850241a04caaae516f27762d0c0cbc716',)))
```

Comment: Are you trying for url 'reservation-details' or 'user-details' ?

Comment: it is `user-details`. I fixed the typo